# Control AdDuplex ads appearing on my WinRT pp

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a windows 8 app and I have integrated adduplex with it. Is there a way to control what size of ads are being served by adduplex on my app? Currently I see 300x250 which messes up my UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, it uses the size property, example size="90x720" will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if AdDuplex uses a WebView to present the ads, but if it doesn't then perhaps you could put it in a Viewbox to scale it down.

Comment: Got it, it uses the size property, example size="90x720" will do the trick